# Intensity Fluxuation when drawing line Lists with Directx9

Tags: lines, directx-9

I'm doing some fooling around with DX9, just for fun, and I've run across a bit of a problem. I'm drawing a whole bunch of vertical lines, all of which are the color white (`0xffffffff`) according to both assignment, and the debugger while its running. However, when drawn, the lines cycle from a bright white to a medium gray when actually drawn. I checked whether it was a problem with my screen by dragging the window around and seeing if the cycle pattern shifted, but it doesn't.

Why is this happening? How  can I fix it?

Comment: Why not paste your code?